# Need help understand interfaces and/or abstract classes in angular2

Tags: rest, typescript, angular

I am new to the angular2 world.  I am trying to create interfaces for certain components and then implement these interfaces in my models so I can make sure they will be able to work properly.

One thing I have noticed is that if I create new instances of these objects they work fine but when I pull data from a restful call, I use the type casting to turn the data into the type of object I expect. The following code is a pseudo example.

I come from a Java/C++ background so I am hoping someone can see what I'm trying to do and explain to me how to get this working correctly.

Thanks In Advance!

Doesn't work ---

```
private vehicles: Vehicle[];

this._vehicleService.loadVehicles().subscribe(
vehicles => this.vehicles = <Vehicle[]>vehicles);
```

Does Work ---
    vehicles : Vehicle[];
    vehicles.push(new Vehicle(1, 'Old Junker'));
    vehicles.push(new Vehicle(2, 'Old Junker2'));

Example class/interface setup.

```
@Component
export class SelectableComponent {
  options : Selectable[]

  // Access options.label and options.value
}

export interface Selectable {
  label(): string;
  value(): any;
}

export class Vehicle implements Selectable {
  constructor (
    public id: number,
    public description: string,
  ){}   

  get label() : any {
    return this.description;
  }

  get value() : any {
    return this.id;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that the object retrieved from the backend is just a plain Javascript object that gets cast to a Vehicle:

```
this._vehicleService.loadVehicles().subscribe(
 vehicles => this.vehicles = <Vehicle[]>vehicles);
```

Objects in this array will have all the data of a Vehicle, but none of the behavior of an instance of the Vehicle class, which can be quite confusing as you mention.

The simplest is instead of casting them, calling new and creating an instance of Vehicle immediately while retrieving them from the backend.

But using a long constructor call can be cumbersome, especially if Vehicle has a lot of properties and you need to pass them all to the constructor one by one.

A way to fix this is to create an auxiliary method in the Vehicle class:

```
class Vehicle {

    constructor(private name, private year) {

    }

    static fromJson({name,year}) {
        return new Vehicle(name, year);
    }
}
```

And then use it in return from the backend to create an array of Vehicles, instead of casting them:

```
this._vehicleService.loadVehicles().subscribe(
    vehicles => this.vehicles = vehicles.map(Vehicle.fromJson));
```

This way the vehicles in the result will have not only all the data of a vehicle, but also the behavior of the Vehicle class, because they are instances on Vehicle.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of.  I like the idea of creating an auxiliary method.  At least that will help.  I find it odd that implementing an interface in Angular2 doesn't behave the way interfaces in Java, C#, etc.  work.  Maybe they will decide to change the current behavior.  I think that would be a big help.  I haven't been a big fan of javascript over the years but this new Angular2 / typescript seems really promising.  Maybe this will be incentive for me to build a http plugin that can initialize the data models upon return.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between classes and interfaces in TypeScript is that interfaces don't exist at runtime. They are "only" there for compilation and type checking.

Casting an element to an interface / class "only" tells TypeScript that the object follows the structure of it but it's not actually an instance of the type. It's a bit disturbing at a first sight. The main consequence (in the case of a class) is that casting doesn't allow you to use methods of the class.

I already casted this way:

```
private vehicles: Vehicle[];

this._vehicleService.loadVehicles().subscribe(
  vehicles => this.vehicles = <Vehicle[]>vehicles);
```

What is the exact compilation error you have?

Comment: Its not a compiler error.  The answer above from Angular University summed it up.  I'm getting back a JSON object and it isn't creating an instance of the type I expect / want.  When I 'new' the object, I get the methods I expect based on the interface it implements.  Casting from a rest call doesn't initialize the class.  It just puts the data in there.  Thanks